# Rspec with I18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am trying to test my existing app that contains some I18n

This is my test:

```
require "spec_helper"
require "rails_helper"

describe "visiting landing page" do
  it "should display the welcome text" do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_text("TUTOS DUCLOS")
  end
end
```

I have the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) visiting landing page should display the welcome text
     Failure/Error: visit root_path

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"landing", :controller=>"home"} missing required keys: [:locale]
     # ./spec/features/home_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00127 seconds (files took 1.89 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/home_spec.rb:7 # visiting landing page should display the welcome text
```

if I change the `root_path`in `"en"`the test passes... But I am not sure if it's correct to do it this way...
Is there something more rails conventional  ?
thanks

### edit

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    get "/best_voted", to: "tutos#best_voted"
    resources :tutos
    namespace :users do
      resources :tutos
    end

    resources :tutos, only: [:show]

    resources :tutos do
      member do
        put "like", to: "tutos#upvote"
      end
    end

  as :user do
    get     "/register",  to: "devise/registrations#new", as: :register
    get     "/login",     to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :login
    get     "/logout",    to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :logout
    get     "/account",   to: "users#show", as: :account
    get     "/login" ,    to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :new_user_session
    post    "/login" ,    to: "devise/sessions#create", as: :user_session
    delete  "/logout" ,   to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :destroy_user_session
  end

    devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions]

    resources :users

    root "home#landing"
  end
  get '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
  get '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the locale as an optional parameter in your routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|fr/ do
  resources :books
end
```

---

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_locale

  private

    def set_locale
       I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    end
end
```

Comment: There are quite a few workarounds available on https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255